# Solving a system of four non-linear differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, nonlinear, system

Could someone help me with my problem? I've been scratching my head over this for a day now. I can't write the right code to solve this non-linear differential equation system:

```
x1'[t] = (2 x2^2 Cos[(2 n \[Pi] - 
     2 ArcTan[(-2 psi2 x1 x2 + 
        Sqrt[(psi1^2 + psi2^2) (-1 + x1^2 + x2^2)^2 (x1^2 + 
           x2^2)^2] + 
        psi1 (x1^4 + x2^2 + x2^4 + 
           x1^2 (-1 + 2 x2^2)))/(-2 psi1 x2 (x1 + x1^2 + x2^2) + 
        psi2 (x1 + x1^2 + (-1 + x2) x2) (x1 + x1^2 + x2 + 
           x2^2))])[t]] + 
x1 (-1 + x1^2 + x2^2 - 
   2 x2 Sin[(2 n \[Pi] - 
        2 ArcTan[(-2 psi2 x1 x2 + 
           Sqrt[(psi1^2 + psi2^2) (-1 + x1^2 + x2^2)^2 (x1^2 + 
              x2^2)^2] + 
           psi1 (x1^4 + x2^2 + x2^4 + 
              x1^2 (-1 + 2 x2^2)))/(-2 psi1 x2 (x1 + x1^2 + 
              x2^2) + 
           psi2 (x1 + x1^2 + (-1 + x2) x2) (x1 + x1^2 + x2 + 
              x2^2))])[t]]))/(1 + x1^2 + x2^2 - 
2 x1 Cos[(2 n \[Pi] - 
     2 ArcTan[(-2 psi2 x1 x2 + 
        Sqrt[(psi1^2 + psi2^2) (-1 + x1^2 + x2^2)^2 (x1^2 + 
           x2^2)^2] + 
        psi1 (x1^4 + x2^2 + x2^4 + 
           x1^2 (-1 + 2 x2^2)))/(-2 psi1 x2 (x1 + x1^2 + x2^2) + 
        psi2 (x1 + x1^2 + (-1 + x2) x2) (x1 + x1^2 + x2 + 
           x2^2))])[t]] - 
2 x2 Sin[(2 n \[Pi] - 
     2 ArcTan[(-2 psi2 x1 x2 + 
        Sqrt[(psi1^2 + psi2^2) (-1 + x1^2 + x2^2)^2 (x1^2 + 
           x2^2)^2] + 
        psi1 (x1^4 + x2^2 + x2^4 + 
           x1^2 (-1 + 2 x2^2)))/(-2 psi1 x2 (x1 + x1^2 + x2^2) + 
        psi2 (x1 + x1^2 + (-1 + x2) x2) (x1 + x1^2 + x2 + 
           x2^2))])[t]])
x2'[t] = (x2 (-1 + x1^2 + x2^2 - 
   2 x1 Cos[(2 n \[Pi] - 
        2 ArcTan[(-2 psi2 x1 x2 + 
           Sqrt[(psi1^2 + psi2^2) (-1 + x1^2 + x2^2)^2 (x1^2 + 
              x2^2)^2] + 
           psi1 (x1^4 + x2^2 + x2^4 + 
              x1^2 (-1 + 2 x2^2)))/(-2 psi1 x2 (x1 + x1^2 + 
              x2^2) + 
           psi2 (x1 + x1^2 + (-1 + x2) x2) (x1 + x1^2 + x2 + 
              x2^2))])[t]]) + 
2 x1^2 Sin[(2 n \[Pi] - 
     2 ArcTan[(-2 psi2 x1 x2 + 
        Sqrt[(psi1^2 + psi2^2) (-1 + x1^2 + x2^2)^2 (x1^2 + 
           x2^2)^2] + 
        psi1 (x1^4 + x2^2 + x2^4 + 
           x1^2 (-1 + 2 x2^2)))/(-2 psi1 x2 (x1 + x1^2 + x2^2) + 
        psi2 (x1 + x1^2 + (-1 + x2) x2) (x1 + x1^2 + x2 + 
           x2^2))])[t]])/(1 + x1^2 + x2^2 - 
2 x1 Cos[(2 n \[Pi] - 
     2 ArcTan[(-2 psi2 x1 x2 + 
        Sqrt[(psi1^2 + psi2^2) (-1 + x1^2 + x2^2)^2 (x1^2 + 
           x2^2)^2] + 
        psi1 (x1^4 + x2^2 + x2^4 + 
           x1^2 (-1 + 2 x2^2)))/(-2 psi1 x2 (x1 + x1^2 + x2^2) + 
        psi2 (x1 + x1^2 + (-1 + x2) x2) (x1 + x1^2 + x2 + 
           x2^2))])[t]] - 
2 x2 Sin[(2 n \[Pi] - 
     2 ArcTan[(-2 psi2 x1 x2 + 
        Sqrt[(psi1^2 + psi2^2) (-1 + x1^2 + x2^2)^2 (x1^2 + 
           x2^2)^2] + 
        psi1 (x1^4 + x2^2 + x2^4 + 
           x1^2 (-1 + 2 x2^2)))/(-2 psi1 x2 (x1 + x1^2 + x2^2) + 
        psi2 (x1 + x1^2 + (-1 + x2) x2) (x1 + x1^2 + x2 + 
           x2^2))])[t]])
psi1'[t] - ((psi1 (-1 + x1^4 + 4 x2^2 + x2^4 + 2 x1^2 (2 + x2^2)) + 
 4 psi2 x1 x2 Cos[
   2 t[2 n \[Pi] - 
      2 ArcTan[(-2 psi2 x1 x2 + 
         Sqrt[(psi1^2 + psi2^2) (-1 + x1^2 + x2^2)^2 (x1^2 + 
            x2^2)^2] + 
         psi1 (x1^4 + x2^2 + x2^4 + 
            x1^2 (-1 + 2 x2^2)))/(-2 psi1 x2 (x1 + x1^2 + x2^2) + 
         psi2 (x1 + x1^2 + (-1 + x2) x2) (x1 + x1^2 + x2 + 
            x2^2))]]] + 
 4 (psi2 x1 - psi1 x2 (x1^2 + x2^2)) Sin[
   t[2 n \[Pi] - 
     2 ArcTan[(-2 psi2 x1 x2 + 
        Sqrt[(psi1^2 + psi2^2) (-1 + x1^2 + x2^2)^2 (x1^2 + 
           x2^2)^2] + 
        psi1 (x1^4 + x2^2 + x2^4 + 
           x1^2 (-1 + 2 x2^2)))/(-2 psi1 x2 (x1 + x1^2 + x2^2) + 
        psi2 (x1 + x1^2 + (-1 + x2) x2) (x1 + x1^2 + x2 + 
           x2^2))]]] - 
 4 Cos[t[2 n \[Pi] - 
     2 ArcTan[(-2 psi2 x1 x2 + 
        Sqrt[(psi1^2 + psi2^2) (-1 + x1^2 + x2^2)^2 (x1^2 + 
           x2^2)^2] + 
        psi1 (x1^4 + x2^2 + x2^4 + 
           x1^2 (-1 + 2 x2^2)))/(-2 psi1 x2 (x1 + x1^2 + x2^2) + 
        psi2 (x1 + x1^2 + (-1 + x2) x2) (x1 + x1^2 + x2 + 
           x2^2))]]] (psi2 x2 + psi1 x1 (x1^2 + x2^2) + 
    psi2 (x1 - x2) (x1 + x2) Sin[
      t[2 n \[Pi] - 
        2 ArcTan[(-2 psi2 x1 x2 + 
           Sqrt[(psi1^2 + psi2^2) (-1 + x1^2 + x2^2)^2 (x1^2 + 
              x2^2)^2] + 
           psi1 (x1^4 + x2^2 + x2^4 + 
              x1^2 (-1 + 2 x2^2)))/(-2 psi1 x2 (x1 + x1^2 + 
              x2^2) + 
           psi2 (x1 + x1^2 + (-1 + x2) x2) (x1 + x1^2 + x2 + 
              x2^2))]]]))/(1 + x1^2 + x2^2 - 
 2 x1 Cos[
   t[2 n \[Pi] - 
     2 ArcTan[(-2 psi2 x1 x2 + 
        Sqrt[(psi1^2 + psi2^2) (-1 + x1^2 + x2^2)^2 (x1^2 + 
           x2^2)^2] + 
        psi1 (x1^4 + x2^2 + x2^4 + 
           x1^2 (-1 + 2 x2^2)))/(-2 psi1 x2 (x1 + x1^2 + x2^2) + 
        psi2 (x1 + x1^2 + (-1 + x2) x2) (x1 + x1^2 + x2 + 
           x2^2))]]] - 
 2 x2 Sin[
   t[2 n \[Pi] - 
     2 ArcTan[(-2 psi2 x1 x2 + 
        Sqrt[(psi1^2 + psi2^2) (-1 + x1^2 + x2^2)^2 (x1^2 + 
           x2^2)^2] + 
        psi1 (x1^4 + x2^2 + x2^4 + 
           x1^2 (-1 + 2 x2^2)))/(-2 psi1 x2 (x1 + x1^2 + x2^2) + 
        psi2 (x1 + x1^2 + (-1 + x2) x2) (x1 + x1^2 + x2 + 
           x2^2))]]])^2)
psi2'[t] = (-psi2 (-1 + x1^4 + 4 x2^2 + x2^4 + 2 x1^2 (2 + x2^2)) + 
4 (-psi1 x2 + psi2 x1 (x1^2 + x2^2)) Cos[
  t[2 n \[Pi] - 
    2 ArcTan[(-2 psi2 x1 x2 + 
       Sqrt[(psi1^2 + psi2^2) (-1 + x1^2 + x2^2)^2 (x1^2 + 
          x2^2)^2] + 
       psi1 (x1^4 + x2^2 + x2^4 + 
          x1^2 (-1 + 2 x2^2)))/(-2 psi1 x2 (x1 + x1^2 + x2^2) + 
       psi2 (x1 + x1^2 + (-1 + x2) x2) (x1 + x1^2 + x2 + 
          x2^2))]]] + 
4 psi1 x1 x2 Cos[
  2 t[2 n \[Pi] - 
     2 ArcTan[(-2 psi2 x1 x2 + 
        Sqrt[(psi1^2 + psi2^2) (-1 + x1^2 + x2^2)^2 (x1^2 + 
           x2^2)^2] + 
        psi1 (x1^4 + x2^2 + x2^4 + 
           x1^2 (-1 + 2 x2^2)))/(-2 psi1 x2 (x1 + x1^2 + x2^2) + 
        psi2 (x1 + x1^2 + (-1 + x2) x2) (x1 + x1^2 + x2 + 
           x2^2))]]] + 
4 (psi1 x1 + psi2 x2 (x1^2 + x2^2)) Sin[
  t[2 n \[Pi] - 
    2 ArcTan[(-2 psi2 x1 x2 + 
       Sqrt[(psi1^2 + psi2^2) (-1 + x1^2 + x2^2)^2 (x1^2 + 
          x2^2)^2] + 
       psi1 (x1^4 + x2^2 + x2^4 + 
          x1^2 (-1 + 2 x2^2)))/(-2 psi1 x2 (x1 + x1^2 + x2^2) + 
       psi2 (x1 + x1^2 + (-1 + x2) x2) (x1 + x1^2 + x2 + 
          x2^2))]]] - 
2 psi1 (x1 - x2) (x1 + x2) Sin[
  2 t[2 n \[Pi] - 
     2 ArcTan[(-2 psi2 x1 x2 + 
        Sqrt[(psi1^2 + psi2^2) (-1 + x1^2 + x2^2)^2 (x1^2 + 
           x2^2)^2] + 
        psi1 (x1^4 + x2^2 + x2^4 + 
           x1^2 (-1 + 2 x2^2)))/(-2 psi1 x2 (x1 + x1^2 + x2^2) + 
        psi2 (x1 + x1^2 + (-1 + x2) x2) (x1 + x1^2 + x2 + 
           x2^2))]]])/(1 + x1^2 + x2^2 - 
2 x1 Cos[
  t[2 n \[Pi] - 
    2 ArcTan[(-2 psi2 x1 x2 + 
       Sqrt[(psi1^2 + psi2^2) (-1 + x1^2 + x2^2)^2 (x1^2 + 
          x2^2)^2] + 
       psi1 (x1^4 + x2^2 + x2^4 + 
          x1^2 (-1 + 2 x2^2)))/(-2 psi1 x2 (x1 + x1^2 + x2^2) + 
       psi2 (x1 + x1^2 + (-1 + x2) x2) (x1 + x1^2 + x2 + 
          x2^2))]]] - 
2 x2 Sin[
  t[2 n \[Pi] - 
    2 ArcTan[(-2 psi2 x1 x2 + 
       Sqrt[(psi1^2 + psi2^2) (-1 + x1^2 + x2^2)^2 (x1^2 + 
          x2^2)^2] + 
       psi1 (x1^4 + x2^2 + x2^4 + 
          x1^2 (-1 + 2 x2^2)))/(-2 psi1 x2 (x1 + x1^2 + x2^2) + 
       psi2 (x1 + x1^2 + (-1 + x2) x2) (x1 + x1^2 + x2 + 
          x2^2))]]])^2
```

I need to find x1 and x2. Initial conditions is: x1(0)=0.8, x2(0) = 0, psi1(0)=1, psi2(0) = tau (-inf < tau < +inf). Also I need to plotting a graphic of this solutions. All my attempts to use DSolve/NDSolve have failed, my computer calculates these solutions and a half hours and eventually gives errors. Hope the community can help.

Comment: You're going to have to write all the functions as x1[t], x2[t], psi1[t], and psi2[t] and not just x1, x2 and so forth.

Comment: @josh okay, I can do this. But what should the code look like? I wrote like this:

eqs={x1'[t]==...,
x2'[t]==...,
psi1'[t]==...,
psi2'[t]==...;
init={x1[1]==0.8,x2[0]==0,psi1[0]==1,psi2[0]==tau};
sol=NDSolveValue[{eqs,init},{x1[t],x2[t],psi1[t],psi2[t]},{t,1,10}];

Plot[sol,{t,1,10}]

But for some reason Mathematica throws a bunch of errors.

Comment: Also noticed you have an undefined "n" in there.  Maybe set it to 1 for now.  Format of NDSolve you wrote is not correct.  Should be NDSolve[{eqn1,eqn2,eqn3,eqn4,x1[0]=a,x2[0]=b,psi1[0]=c,psi2=d},{x1,x2,psi1,psi2},{t,0,1}] for example.  I made a mistake above telling you ALL functions need to be x1[t] and so forth.  That true in the body of the DE but not in the return function names as I wrote here.  Also, need double equal signs for function def like x1'[t]==body and so forth.

Comment: Also:  you have constructs such as : Sin[t[2 n \[Pi] - 2 ArcTan[. . .  You can't use square brackets to group expressions.  Need to replace all of these with parentheses.  I tried but still ran into problems.  How about this:  separate each equation as eqn1=x1[t]==...  into a separate notebook cell and edit them, press Enter until you get no errors.  Then can write:  myEqns={eqn1,eqn2,eqn3,eqn4}.

Comment: Okay, I brought my code to this format: 

NDSolve[{x1'[t]==..., x2'[t]==..., psi1'[t]==..., psi2'[t]==...,x1[0]=0.8,
x2[0]=0,
psi1[0]=1,
psi2[0]=5},{x1,x2,psi1,psi2},{t,0,1}]

I put n = 1 and changed all x1, x2, psi1, psi2 to x1[t], x2[t], psi1[t], psi2[t] in DE body. Now I catch this error: Equation or list of equations expected instead of 0.8` in the first argument. I think somewhere near x1(0) = 0.8 is a syntax problem. 

About brackets. Yes, there was a mistake, I fix it.

Is there a way to attach a code file here? I think it would make debugging easier.

Comment: Ok.  Now you've incorrectly initialized all the x1, x2 and so forth  by not using == and may have other init errors. Easiest way to eliminate this is to save notebook, exit Mathematica, and start notebook again.  Another suggestion:  If you continue to have problems, then cut way down your equations to a visually-manageable size just to get NDSolve working.  Now add back to one equation. Still giving you a solution?  Then add back the entire expression for eqn1.  Then do the second.  Continue this way until you get what you want.

Comment: Also, I don't think many here want to download an unfamiliar file to their machine.  Best way is to update your post above with the corrected code so we can easily cut it and paste it into a notebook but preferably without any syntax errors.

Comment: Yes, there was some kind of glitch with the program. I reload notebook. Now at the output I have x1, x2 -> InterpolatingFunction and small picture next both of x1 and x2. How can I plot x1 and x2? I have sol = NDSolve{...}, next is Plot[sol,{t,0,10}], but it plotting empty coordinate grid.

Comment: Okay, sorry, I found how to plot x1 and x2. Thanks for your answers, Josh. I'm really grateful to you.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks.  Nice job addressing the issues, fixing them and solving it.